How to run X-frame-option deny/sameorigin on a website (Iframe)
I need to showcase a certain site with work instructions in an Iframe container or any sort of container on HTML.
On that certain website frame options are set to same-origin or deny. Is there a workaround?
If there is another workaround to show that data of the site on my local web application that is more than perfect too!
I have tried Iframes.
I'm exploring the Jquery - Ajax method but no luck so far.
